# Хранение сессии Requests Python с авторизацией VK

Tags: python, вконтакте, requests

У меня на сайте происходит парсинг выбранного сообщества вк. На данный момент при каждом запросе происходит новая авторизация через форму с вводом логина и пароля.
`response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())`
Сразу скажу, через api вытащить нужные данные (Организатора встречи) нельзя.
Вопрос стоит в том, могу ли я как-то авторизоваться один раз, сохранить данные сессии и потом просто их дергать из бд, чтобы отправлять новые запросы? Как это сделать?

Comment: так сделай акк и сохрани токен, а потом посылай запрос с токеном без авторизации

Answer (score -1, accepted):

все что нужно это сохранить куки полученные после авторизации и использовать их при следующих запросах

если ты используешь класс requests.Session, то он все сделает сам.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects